# Firing event and getting the title of the button Titanium

Tags: javascript, dom-events, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have created an array of 4 buttons with each of the button have a title. Now, when clicked I want to display the title of the button clicked in an alert bar saying:

> You have clicked the "title" button

I need help with adding such events in Titanium.

Here is my code :

```
var buttons = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          buttons[i] = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title:titleArray[i],
            width : 250,
            height : 250,
            right : (280 * (1 + i)),
            top:90,
        });
        window1.add(buttons[i]);
        
}

Ti.App.addEventListener('click', function(e) {  
            alert(e.buttons.title);  
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the listener code inside the for loop:

```
var buttons = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          buttons[i] = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title:titleArray[i],
            width : 250,
            height : 250,
            right : (280 * (1 + i)),
            top:90,
        });
        window1.add(buttons[i]);

        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

           alert(e.source.title);
       })

}
```